# ‘Jenkins’ missing node label ‘master’ after v. 2.307+ upgrade

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After upgrading to 2.307 and applying terminology changes (from 'master' to 'Built-In Node'), my builds stopped working with the following error message:
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘master’

My Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
node('master') {
    dir('build') {
        stage('Checkout') {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It helps to [read the Changelog](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.307) when upgrading.
You can also just look up the node in Jenkins.

> - Replace the term "**master**" with "**controller**" (for the main Jenkins application) or "**built-in node**", as appropriate. ([pull
>   5425](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/5425))
> - Add migration code to only change the node name (e.g. `NODE_NAME` environment variable) and label of the built-in node after explicit
>   migration by an administrator. New installations get the new node and
>   and label immediately. ([pull 5425](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/5425))
> - Add the system property `jenkins.model.Jenkins.nodeNameAndSelfLabelOverride` to specify a
>   different node name and label for the built-in node (e.g. for
>   Configuration as Code use cases) than the one otherwise determined.
>   This will not affect other uses of the node name, such as the URL to
>   the built-in node (now `/computer/(built-in)/`). ([pull 5425](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/5425))

**Clarification:**

If your Job definition, Pipeline definition, or Tool installer reference must be tied to the built-in node, it should use the label "`built-in`" instead of "`master`". Using the **built-in** (formerly master) node is [strongly discouraged](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/controller-isolation/).

The new Nodes url (as shown below) is: `${JENKINS_URL}/computer/(built-in)/` instead of `${JENKINS_URL}/computer/(master)/`

[image: Built-In node]

---

**Alternative:**
It is possible to continue the existing configuration by adding "**master**" as a label to the "`built-in`" node.

[image: Built-In label:master]

Comment: While I did read the changelog, I did not find in it that the default label for the built-in node is "built-in". I tried with just "Built-In Node" which didn't work, that's why I figured I wouldn't be the only one having some issues upgrading.

Comment: Agree the wording could be better. The first bullet really applies from a "documentation" perspective.  The second bullet reflects the code change to call it "built-in", built is not explicitly stated that's the new name.

Comment: @Sharp, The changelog wording is being updated. I have added clarification. If you found this answer useful, consider upvoting and / or marking as answered. That will help give this answer visibility for others.

Comment: Is it `built-in` or `(built-in)` with the parenthesis? On `/computer` the URL suggests it needs the parenthesis, while other nodes omit them.

Comment: The url is: `${JENKINSURL}/manage/computer/(built-in)/`. The label is "**built-in**". I don't know why the difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your pipeline to be compatible with both recent and old versions, you can use a label expression such as `master || built-in`.

#### Examples

- Scripted pipeline

  ```
  node('master || built-in') {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  Reference : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node
- Declarative pipeline

  ```
  pipeline {
      agent {
          label 'master || built-in'
      }
      // ...
  }
  ```

  Reference : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent
- Job DSL

  ```
  job('example') {
      label('master || built-in')
      // ...
  }
  ```

  Reference : https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.job-label

Answer (score 0):

In case you have only one node or don't care at which node is your build run, you can just remove the specific node name:

```
node {
    dir('build') {
        stage('Checkout') {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can go to the Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes and Clouds, then press downwards-arrow when you hover over a node's name and press Configure. Here you can add a label that you can then use in your Jenkinsfile as above.